# Could not create connection to database server

Tags: android, mysql, database, connection, database-connection

I'm developing an app for Android in Eclipse.
My problem is that when I try to connect to my database in mysql from my Android Application i get an error

03-13 21:25:55.296: W/System.err(1197): com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server.

I'm relative new with database connections and I dont know what I'm doing wrong

I let you here some code

```
package com.example.login;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class ConectorDDBB {

static String iP = "127.0.0.1";
static String puerto = "3306";
static String userDDBB = "bruno";
static String passwordDDBB= "bruno1234";


public boolean conectarDDBB(String user, String password){
    String conexionMySQL = "jdbc:mysql://"+ iP + ":" + puerto;
    Connection con = null;
    Boolean login = false;
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(conexionMySQL, userDDBB, passwordDDBB);

        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM login"); 

        while (rs.next()){
            if (rs.getString("User").equals(user))
                login = true;
        }


        con.close();
        st.close();
        rs.close();

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return login;
}
```

}

I have been create a database in mysql with a table called login
All the parameters IP Port user and password are right... so i dont understand why i cant connect
if someone could help me..
than you very much in advance

Comment: Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15853367/jdbc-vs-web-service-for-android

Comment: Thank you Patrick, i used a web service ainsted connectors and it worked